# Express / NextJS - Multiple directories in a single express route

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm using NextJS / Express to create a website to share articles on.

I have an article page nested within the pages directory (pages/articles.js)

I would like to have multiple subdirectories reroute to this template based on a category (

```
server.get(`/${"category-1" || "category-2" || "category-3"}/:id`, (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = "/articles";
      const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });
```

When using the above snippet it seems to work on refresh with /category-1/:id but not /category-2/:id or /category-3/:id

The intended functionality works when I split them into their own individual get chunks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
server.get('/:category(category-1|category-2|category-3)/:id', (req, res) => {
  // Parameters: req.params.category and req.params.id.
  const actualPage = "/articles";
  const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
});
```

`||` is logical OR (also first no-false value). Javascript will evaluate `0 || 1 || 2` as `1`.

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for the answer -- does category in /:category signify anything or can that be any random string?

Comment: Both :category and :id are parameters. that you can name as you want. But :category can only take values from enum: "category-1", "category-2" or "category-3".

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond on the answer and answering the logical issue that I had as well as the one defined in the title!